# Statistical test to use?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

Which statistical test should I use for prediction if there are 5 qualitative independent variables and 1 quantitative independent variable?

Comment: why would you use a *test* for *prediction*? - they're different tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with GLM, I am guessing you are looking for which model you should use. That depends upon you dependent variable. If you are trying to predict a continuous value, linear regression is likely the best model.

If you are trying to create a binary classifier, then you would probably use logistic regression. Logistic regression deals with modeling the log odds of an event.

If you are trying to predict a discrete (non-binary) number (such as a count expected for a unit time), then Poisson regression may work, unless the assumption of Poisson distribution is too far off. In that case, you may want to look at negative binomial regression.

What are you trying to predict?

Comment: however, can I apply regression in this case for prediction if independent variables are qualitative and quantitative?

Comment: Let me share with you some real data: I am  trying to set an equation which could predict well in advance whether the client will close the account with us depending upon certain parameters. I have assigned value as 1 for 1 account closed with corresponding independent variables (5 qualitative and 1 quantitative). For eg; 1st row has 1 as value for the 1 closed account user likewise I have 140 such users everyone has been assigned the value of 1. Please state which model should I use?